# OpenGL 2d sprite not rendering (OpenTK)

Tags: c#, opengl, graphics, opentk

I have been working on a render and it has been working OK for one texture but would not render a second. I seemed to have changed something and it stopped rendering anything but the background color. I am not sure what I changed and I cannot get it back to the way it was. I try not to post lots of code at once onto here but I do not know enough OpenGL to isolate the issue. If you can offer any help or hints, I would greatly appreciate it!

My guess is that it is either coming from the way I am binding the coordinate or the shader.

The following is the code:

Shaders:

```
       string vertexShaderSource = @"
                        #version 330

                        layout (location = 0) in vec3 Position;

                        uniform mat4 projectionmatrix;
                        uniform mat4 ModelMatrix;
                        uniform mat4 ViewMatrix;

                        attribute vec2 texcoord;
                        varying vec2 f_texcoord;

                        uniform vec2 pos;

                        void main()
                        {
                            f_texcoord = texcoord;
                            gl_Position = projectionmatrix * vec4(Position, 1);

                            //gl_Position = projectionmatrix * vec4(Position.xyz, 1.0);
                        }
                    ";

    string fragmentShaderSource = @"
                    #version 330

                    out vec4 FragColor;

                    varying vec2 f_texcoord;
                    uniform sampler2D mytexture;

                    void main()
                    {
                        FragColor = texture2D(mytexture, f_texcoord);
                        //FragColor = Vec4(0,0,0, 1);
                    }";
```

Vertexes:

```
    Vector2[] g_vertex_buffer_data ={
            new Vector2(-1.0f, 1.0f),
            new Vector2(1.0f, 1.0f),
            new Vector2(1.0f, -1.0f),
            new Vector2(-1.0f, -1.0f)
    };


    Vector2[] g_texture_coords = {
            new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f),
            new Vector2(1.0f, 0.0f),
            new Vector2(1.0f, -1.0f),
            new Vector2(0.0f, -1.0f)
    };
```

Shader setup:

```
        shaderProgramHandle = GL.CreateProgram();

        vertexShaderHandle = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.VertexShader);
        fragmentShaderHandle = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.FragmentShader);

        GL.ShaderSource(vertexShaderHandle, vertexShaderSource);
        GL.ShaderSource(fragmentShaderHandle, fragmentShaderSource);

        GL.CompileShader(vertexShaderHandle);
        GL.CompileShader(fragmentShaderHandle);

        GL.AttachShader(shaderProgramHandle, vertexShaderHandle);
        GL.AttachShader(shaderProgramHandle, fragmentShaderHandle);

        GL.LinkProgram(shaderProgramHandle);
        GL.UseProgram(shaderProgramHandle);
```

Basic setup and binding:

GL.ClearColor(Color4.Red);

```
        //GL.LoadMatrix(ref projectionMatrix);

        GL.GenBuffers(2, out vertexbuffer);

        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vertexbuffer);

        GL.BufferData<Vector2>(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer,
                               new IntPtr(g_vertex_buffer_data.Length * Vector2.SizeInBytes),
                               g_vertex_buffer_data, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

        //Shader Setup
        CreateShaders();

        Matrix4 projectionMatrix = Matrix4.CreateOrthographic(control.Width, control.Height, -1, 1);

        vertexShaderProjectionHandle = GL.GetUniformLocation(shaderProgramHandle, "projectionmatrix");
        GL.UniformMatrix4(vertexShaderProjectionHandle, false, ref projectionMatrix);

        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vertexbuffer);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0);
```

Loading and binding the texture:

```
        GL.BlendFunc(BlendingFactorSrc.SrcAlpha, BlendingFactorDest.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.Blend);

        GL.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture0 + texture.textureID);
        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, texture.textureID);

        textureHandle = GL.GetAttribLocation(shaderProgramHandle, "texcoord");

        GL.GenBuffers(1, out textureBufferHandle);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, textureBufferHandle);
        GL.BufferData<Vector2>(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, new IntPtr(Vector2.SizeInBytes * 4), g_texture_coords, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
```

Matrix Setup:

```
        //rotation += MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(1);

        float displayRatio = ((float)control.Height / (float)control.Width);

        Matrix4 ViewMatrix = Matrix4.Identity;

        int ViewMatrixHandle = GL.GetUniformLocation(shaderProgramHandle, "ViewMatrix");
        GL.UniformMatrix4(ViewMatrixHandle, true, ref ViewMatrix);

        Matrix4 ModelMatrix = Matrix4.Identity;

        int modelMatrixHandle = GL.GetUniformLocation(shaderProgramHandle, "ModelMatrix");
        GL.UniformMatrix4(modelMatrixHandle, true, ref ModelMatrix);


        int posHandle = GL.GetUniformLocation(shaderProgramHandle, "pos");
        GL.Uniform2(posHandle, ref offset);
```

Rendering

```
        GL.Viewport(0, 0, control.Width, control.Height);

        //GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);

        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

        GL.BindVertexArray(0);

        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(textureHandle);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, textureBufferHandle);

        GL.VertexAttribPointer(textureHandle, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0);

        GL.DrawArrays(BeginMode.Quads, 0, 4);

        GL.Flush();
        control.SwapBuffers();
```

Comment: Two is for the size parameter. The vertexes are composed on Vector2, or 2 float coordinates. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I misread the API call, because I was too busy trying to figure out where `textureHandle` was defined (it was in a different code snippet). But the problem remains that you are using `attribute` when that is invalid in GLSL 330, use `in`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the old `attribute` qualifier to declare `texcoord` in your vertex shader. This is invalid in GLSL 330, and I suspect if you read the program/shader info logs when you compile/link your GLSL program it includes this information in the log.

To correct this, replace `attribute vec2 texcoord` with `in vec2 texcoord`. Then you should get a valid location when you query the attribute location, which is required to set your vertex attribute pointer correctly.

`varying` is also invalid in GLSL 330. You need to declare `f_texcoord` as `out` in your vertex shader and `in` in your fragment shader for your program to properly link.

*There is no error detecting code at all in your code listings. You should read the manual pages for `glValidateProgram (...)`, `glGetProgramInfoLog (...)` and `glGetShaderInfoLog (...)`, because I am pretty sure the GLSL compiler would have told you your exact problem if you read its output log.*

Comment: Hmmm, this does not solve my issue unfortunately unless I am miss understanding you. I have replaced the "attribute" with "in". The query is successful returning 1. I have traced the logs, by using:
GL.GetShaderInfoLog(vertexShaderHandle); which returns nothing unfortunately... hmmm. Maybe my buffers are not being properly binding?

Comment: @SergueiFedorov: I should add to that that `varying` is also invalid. Replace `varying vec2 f_texcoord` with `out vec2 f_texcoord` in your vertex shader and `in vec2 f_texcoord` in your fragment shader.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the invalid commands. I am fairly new to this and it seems like tutorials are a bit scattered as far as the shaders go.

Comment: Could it be that something to do with the sprite rendering off the screen? Hmmm...

Comment: @SergueiFedorov: That is a possibility too. Without knowing what you changed the only thing I can do is point out parts of your shaders that are invalid and hope they are to blame... version control would help a lot in the future if you change things you do not completely understand (e.g. if you make modifications from a working tutorial). A diff would pinpoint exactly where to focus your search.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I found the issue; the issue is that the sprite was very small and scaled against the projection did not render. The issue now is that I when I try to render multiple sprites, they render in different locations (if I add vec4(pos, 0, 1) to the position), but they are flickering and disappearing... Thanks to you I have both the textures rendering now though with a slight issue